# Problems with computing Integral in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, bessel-functions

So I've been trying to use the general integration method (quad) from Scipy on numpy on a specific expression; however, I get the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
```

Here is the function I'm trying to integrate (seems like theres no mathjax here):

integral from 0 to a of   t*y(t) * J0(u_{i} * t/a) dt 
where a is the length of y(t), J0 is a zeroth-order Bessel Function 
and u_{i} is the roots of J0(u) = 0

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.special import *
y = np.load('dataset.npy')  # 1000 pts long
a = 1000
roots = jn_zeros(0, 1000)
func = lambda t: t * jv(0, t * (roots/a) )
result = integrate.quad(func * y , 0, a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you are not calling your function, what you meant was

```
func(y)*y
```

otherwise you are just multiplying a function name by a number/array, which is the error you are seeing. Beyond that, the initial argument to `integrate.quad` is a callable, which is the function you want to integrate. It does not accept a vector, so your initial `y` vector is completely ignored. If anything, you want this:

```
result = integrate.quad(lambda y: func(y) * y , 0, a)
```

but this ignored the dataset completely. To integrate on samples use [trapz, or simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), which accept an `x` array, and a `y` array. You probably need to generate your `y` array using `np.linspace` or something similar.

Comment: I noticed the `arr` typo, but let's make it a pun intended.

Comment: Thanks! but now it seems like I got the following error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (1000,)

Comment: @Sam Looks like `func` is returning a matrix.  You did not post enough info to debug this ([mcve]). I suggest you write a new question for your new problem, but only after you looked around at what `func` is returning and if it makes sense to you.